# Indexing with preg_match

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I am trying to index a website and my preg_match returns an empty array.

This is what I have so far:

```
$content = get_content("www.something.com");
preg_match_all('#<span class="box_cod">Cod: ([0-9\.]*)</span><span class="box_pret">PRET: (.*)</span>#',$content,$Produs);
```

Where get_content is a curl function to retrieve the site.

Thank you!

Comment: It's very difficult to parse HTML with regular expressions. Have you considered using a real DOM parser?

Comment: Excellent... another opportunity to tell someone about [Tony The Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)! I'll never tire of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse and get the site content in a variable. 
For example first you include the php file..

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

its easy than parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: I never used simple html dom parser before and I am not familiar with it, that is why I tried using regular expressions.

Comment: Ok but I need with preg_match_all for now, If I only leave just the first one with Cod, the code works perfectly, if I add PRET then it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for nothing,  i made it with 2 preg_match'es.